# How does Android stock Gallery app work without OutOfMemory?

Tags: android, bitmap

For a time I have been fighting with showing images from camera in their natural resolution without OutOfMemory Exception. Even Google Developer website doesn't speak about it, they recommend scaling using `options.inJustDecodeBounds = true` but I don't want to scale image.
I was digging SO and didn't find answer, there are different ways like tiling etc. but *I am very curious what is approach in Android stock Gallery app*, it can show even huge photos without problems. Why Android doesn't have this ability and I can't do it with some default view like in i.e. iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Android Gallery previews those bitmaps with way less resolution then original until one of the image is chosen and brought to full screen. Previewing all of the thumbnails with original resolution won't make images look better.

It doesn't matter which operating system are you developing for, both systems need lots of ram when reading bitmap pixels.

So what should you do? You should load the scaled down bitmap into memory.

Take a look here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html
There are steps how to make your app work with bitmaps efficiently

Or use this library https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question.

Comment: So what was the question?